# input value for LIMIT(unitest)

Tags: python, sql

I'm currently confused on this one. limit by default is none, but if i were to test this in unitest and ask a specific number of comments it would say type mismatch. I know that "int" is not the correct term. I'm only saying that the limit should be an integer. What would be the proper way of addressing the input depending on what the limit is in the unitest.

```
def list_comments(db, limit=None): limit = "int"
    limit = "int"

    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT id, comment FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?", (limit,))
    results = cur.fetchall()

    print results

    return results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `limit = "int"` from behind the function, and make the `limit` parameter default to `0` and use placeholder as `%s`;

```
def list_comments(db, limit=0):
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT id, comment FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT %s", (str(limit)))
    results = cur.fetchall()

    print results

    return results
```

Also remove the comma if it's not needed yet; `(limit,)`.

I've parsed the limit value as a string on purpose (you can check for it initially if it's really a integer) to let it always match the `%s` placeholder.

Comment: i seem to be getting a "OperationalError: near "%": syntax error" Thoughts?

Comment: If it was 0 I should return zero results.  If it is None I should return all the results.  I need two different queries to cover the two cases. Thoughts?